# Issue getting segment from Asp.net Friendly Url

Tags: c#, asp.net, friendly-url

I am using `Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls`. Everything is working as supposed to basically i have made a page test.aspx.

And `www.abc.com/cow` should direct to  `test.aspx`

This part is working fine however on the test.aspx i want to get `cow` which i am trying to get using:

```
   IList<string> segments = Request.GetFriendlyUrlSegments();
```

However it returns nothing.

Any suggestions what am i doing wrong here.

Comment: I am feeling much like your username. What? What do you mean that `www.abc.com/cow` should direct to `test.aspx` ? What's the full requested url you are on when that code get's hit?

Comment: when user hits www.abc.com/cow at the back it points to www.abc.com/test.aspx
Which works fine the thing is cow should be coming as a segment which it is not..